# Bcrypt VS Scrypt, Again?

Tags: passwords, bcrypt, scrypt

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226513/whats-the-advantage-of-scrypt-over-bcrypt) on SO, but the answer was short, and the subject was closed,

What i don't understand, is:
Which one of the two limits memory usage to avoid custom Hardware to break the password?

Edit: there is an excellent discussion for beginners like me [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9149/discussion-between-woliveirajr-and-abdelouahab-pp):

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The scrypt function is specifically designed to hinder such attempts by raising the resource demands of the algorithm. Specifically, the algorithm is designed to use a large amount of memory compared to other password-based KDFs, making the size and the cost of a hardware implementation much more expensive, and therefore limiting the amount of paralleling an attacker can use (for a given amount of financial resources).

It means that some hashing algorithms use few memory, so that specific, custom hardware can be created to brute-force it. Since they use few memory, those hardware aren't that expansive, and can be done, at some extent.

When you require a large ammount of memory, you assure it won't fit in those L1, L2 and even L3 caches of the processor, so external memory (slower) will be accessed. And also means that a custom hardware will require a large ammount of memory, for each processor, and that is very expensive, specially if it is fast...

*edit* Yes, including PBKDF2.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt

*edit 2*: also read the accepted answer on this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage

Comment: but other KDFs, it means PBKDF2 too?

Comment: and Bcrypt uses the same approach? because am lost between the three, Bcrypt is better than PBKDF2 because of using custom memory? then Bcrypt and Scrypt differs only in the amount of memory used? (excluding pbkdf2 that dont use this approach)

Comment: according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2#Alternatives_to_PBKDF2 , scrypt would be better than bcrypt, that would be better than pbkdf2. But scrypt isn't widely used, so it might have some weakness not yet discovered...

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp edited again my answer...

Comment: so from this: SHA-256, for instance, can be very efficiently implemented on a GPU... i understand that Bcrypt is slow because it uses Blowfish? so Scrypt is better because of Salsa?

Comment: it uses salsa/20 and some other things... take a look at http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-josefsson-scrypt-kdf-01#page-3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9149/discussion-between-woliveirajr-and-abdelouahab-pp)